# Инициализация начальных переменных FLUTTER, как правильно?

Tags: flutter

Есть приложение, в нем несколько равнозначных экранов. Один из них карта. Для инициализации карты необходимы стартовые координаты. Для управления создал к карте контроллер. Где храню эти координаты. При инициализации контроллера записываю туда координаты 0, 0. Потом в конструкторе Контроллера считываю из SharedPreferences сохраненные значения и переписываю первоначальные. Карта же считывает данные из контролера (GET) при создании один раз. Хотелось бы - чтоб карта считывала сохраненные значения. А не те, что попали туда при инициализации класса.

лог отладки

```
I/flutter (27013): --> init widget and init position 0.0 0.0 3.0 (build widget)
I/flutter (27013): --> init camera setting from disk 55.698817013724856 29.248157623831418 3.0 (load)
```

Данные картой считываются один раз при создании widget. Поток туда не подашь. Задерживать создание карты - то же не правильно. Что то я упускаю в основах Дарта и Флаттера.
Расположение Контроллера на одном уровне с картой (в том же виджете) и на один уровень выше не решает проблему. Только создание Контроллера на два уровня выше карты, как то помогло. Но думаю это случайность. Усложнив контроллер могу снова не успеть проинициализировать нужными данными.

```
MainApp -> Home -> Map + Controller ( не работает)
MainApp -> Home + Controller -> Map (не работает)
MainApp + Controller -> Home -> Map (вроде получилось)
```

инициализация карты

```
initialCameraPosition:
     // стартовая позиция
     CameraPosition(
       target: LatLng(
         cam.cameraSetting.latitude,
         cam.cameraSetting.longitude),
       zoom: cam.cameraSetting.zoom)),
```

создание контроллера

```
final CameraController cam = CameraController();
```

Передача контроллера вниз по дереву

```
Provider<CameraController>.value(value: cam),
```

В каком направлении думать? При Создании Виджета с картой, мне уже нужны данные из контроллера с выполненной загрузкой из хранилища. Есть способы управления порядком выполнения ASYNC процессов. Или другие правильные решения таких задач?

Answer (score 1):

В `StatefulWidget` есть метод `initState` который можно переопределить. В нем и следует получать контролер и его данные. `initState` вызывается один раз до первой прорисовки кадра.

Comment: Это решение не подходит. Если смотреть диаграмму и последовательность действий виджета с состоянием - вы увидите, что основное создание виджета проходит после операции CREATE. InitState - на созданный виджет с картой не влияет. Что я и получал. https://wsofter.ru/razjasnenie-ponjatij-widget-state-context-inheritedwidget/

Answer (score 1):

я решил по другому. Так как использую BLOC и Stream. до получения реальных координат, я выдаю FALSE и соотвественно вместо карты, показываю индикатор загрузки.

Comment: Думаю тебе стоит добавить несколько состояний для этого экрана, если состояние Loading, то показываешь индикатор загрузки, если загрузился то показываешь карту.